# Function composition in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Can Clojure implement (g ∘ f) constructions like Haskell's `g . f`? I'm currently using workarounds like `(fn [n] (not (zero? n)))`, which isn't nearly as nice :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is a function to do this in `clojure.core` called `comp`. E.g.

```
((comp not zero?) 5)
; => true
```

You might also want to consider using `->` / `->>`, e.g.

```
(-> 5 zero? not)
; => true
```

Comment: Make sure to use `partial` when you would do "currying" in Haskell.  So for map/reduce, you'd need to do `(let [reducer (comp (partial reduce +) (partial map get-value))] (reducer my-things))`

Comment: Also `comp not` can be replaced with `complement`: `((complement zero?) 5)`

Answer (score 13):

You can use Clojure's reader-macro shortcut for anonymous functions to rewrite your version in fewer keystrokes.

```
user=> (#(not (zero? %)) 1)
true
```

For the specific case of composing `not` and another function, you can use `complement`.

```
user=> ((complement zero?) 1)
true
```

Using `not` in combination with `when` and `if` is common enough that `if-not` and `when-not` are core functions.

```
user=> (if-not (zero? 1) :nonzero :zero)
:nonzero
```

Comment: The reader-macro shortcut seems very useful as the code is succinct and readable. I also didn't know about "if-not" and "when-not", thanks!

Comment: *core macros. `if-not` and `when-not` are macros, so there's no runtime cost.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is `(reduce #(%2 %1) n [zero? not])` but I like `(comp not zero?)`, already mentioned by Michal, better.